# display quantity field in table in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my table to look like this

http://gyazo.com/6a134b723c30e97fa99559158cde4b1e

but when I use my code looks like this

http://gyazo.com/1c08f83e744b3a20c99b55eee5313045

I can't get the quantity field or add field to work for the life of me; the quantity field is just blank. I would greatly appreciate some help because I can't get it to work.

```
            <?php require_once("include/db_connect.php"); ?>
            <html>
            <head><title>Displaying Image files using PHP</title></head>
            <body>
            <h1>Displaying Images from an Image table using PHP</h1>

            <?php


            $db_link = db_connect("project");

            // Retrieve table properties

            $fields = mysql_list_fields("project", "bookstore");
            $num_columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

            // Make a simple database query to select all columns and rows

            $query = "SELECT * FROM bookstore";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL query failed");

            // Display results as an HTML table. Note how mysql_field name
            // uses the $fields object to extract the column names

            echo '<table border="1" cellpadding = "5" >';

            // Display the column names

            echo "<tr>";
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++)
            {
               echo "<th>", mysql_field_name($fields, $i), "</th>";
            }

                  echo "<th>"Quantity "</th>";

            echo "</tr>";

            // Loop over the rows of the table.
            // $row contains the information for each row
            // Refer to the names of the fields in the table
            // Must ahow the path where the image files are held

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
               echo "<tr>
               <form action='somethingToHandleForm.php' method='post'>";

               echo "<td>". $row['isbn']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>". $row['title']."</td>";
               echo "<td>". $row['author']."</td>";
               echo "<td>". $row['pub']."</td>";
               echo "<td>". $row['year']."</td>";
               echo "<td>". $row['price']."</td>";
               echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' value=".$row['quantity']."/></td>";
               echo "<td><input type='submit' value='add></td>";
               echo "</form>";

               echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";

            // Free the resources and close the connection

            mysql_free_result($result);
            mysql_close($db_link);
            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I noticed is you're missing a single quote in this line after value=add:

```
<input type='submit' value='add>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some formatting problems in your HTML, which look to be the source of your problems when rendering the table. Specifically the lines:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' value=".$row['quantity']."/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='add></td>";
```

The `value` attribute for the first line is not properly enclosed in quotes, and there is no end single-quote for the value `add` in the second line (nor are you closing the `input` tag), try the following:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' value='".$row['quantity']."' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='add' /></td>";
```